# Android google maps drawing oval instead of circle issue

Tags: android, google-maps, resize, geometry

I have been working on google maps v2 drawing a circle which can be resized on dragging circumference of the circle.

```
Cirlce circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(center)
            .radius(radius)
            .strokeWidth(2)
            .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
            .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#500084d3")));
```

Now problem comes for large value of radius the circle becomes and oval.

I have referred these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991301/android-maps-api-v2-draw-circle?rq=1) and also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795339/circle-drawable-looks-like-oval-on-map)but didnt find any solution:

These links says that
"
the reason you're getting ellipse it's because the math on the options.add( is very basic and pretends the earth is a flat surface, just like before Copernicus. If you draw it on smaller areas you'll get a rounder circle. If you want a precise circle you'll have extend that math to proper take into account the shape of Earth "

Is there any solution to this problem.
Is use of class extending Overlay recommended in google maps v2 so that I can somehow use its onDraw(..) method.

Comment: whats the problem basically ? I dont get you.

Comment: The problem is for larger values of radius ,I am not getting perfect circle .It turns out to be an oval

Comment: there is no `Overlay` class in maps v2, you can try using `GroundOverlay`though

Comment: @tyczj Thanks!! I have used GroundOverlay with following code by spes
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358328/how-to-draw-circle-around-a-pin-using-google-maps-api-v2)